# Can not deserialize instance of JsonGen out of START_ARRAY token : newbee

Tags: java, json, selenium, jackson

I am very new in JSON parsing with JACKSON, Little about what I am trying to achieve -
I have to parse the JSON values and collect it to compare the collected values with Live content which I am retrieving  using selenium, I have used genson to create object classes for json.

JsonGen.java of my program -

```
import java.util.List;

public class JsonGen{
    private String _type;
    private List cast;
    private List clips;
    private Common_sense_data common_sense_data;
    private String common_sense_id;
    private List crew;
    private String description;
    private List episodes;
    private Number franchise_id;
    private List genres;
    private String guid;
    private Images images;
    private boolean is_locked;
    private boolean is_mobile;
    private boolean is_parental_locked;
    private String kind;
    private String mobile_networks;
    private String most_recent_full_episode_added_date;
    private String name;
    private List networks;
    private String platforms;
    private List ratings;
    private String release_date;
    private List season_filters;
    private String slug;
    private String tms_id;



import java.util.List;

public class Cast{
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String middle_name;

    public String getFirst_name(){
        return this.first_name;
    }
    public void setFirst_name(String first_name){
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }
    public String getLast_name(){
        return this.last_name;
    }
    public void setLast_name(String last_name){
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }
    public String getMiddle_name(){
        return this.middle_name;
    }
    public void setMiddle_name(String middle_name){
        this.middle_name = middle_name;
    }
}




import java.util.List;

public class Clips{
    private String description;
    private boolean is_locked;
    private boolean is_parental_locked;
    private Number run_time;
    private String slug;
    private List streams;
    private String thumbnail_url;
    private String title;

    public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    public boolean getIs_locked(){
        return this.is_locked;
    }
    public void setIs_locked(boolean is_locked){
        this.is_locked = is_locked;
    }
    public boolean getIs_parental_locked(){
        return this.is_parental_locked;
    }
    public void setIs_parental_locked(boolean is_parental_locked){
        this.is_parental_locked = is_parental_locked;
    }
    public Number getRun_time(){
        return this.run_time;
    }
    public void setRun_time(Number run_time){
        this.run_time = run_time;
    }
    public String getSlug(){
        return this.slug;
    }
    public void setSlug(String slug){
        this.slug = slug;
    }
    public List getStreams(){
        return this.streams;
    }
    public void setStreams(List streams){
        this.streams = streams;
    }
    public String getThumbnail_url(){
        return this.thumbnail_url;
    }
    public void setThumbnail_url(String thumbnail_url){
        this.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }
}




import java.util.List;

public class Common_sense_data{
    private Slider slider;

    public Slider getSlider(){
        return this.slider;
    }
    public void setSlider(Slider slider){
        this.slider = slider;
    }
}



import java.util.List;

public class Crew{
    private List members;
    private String role;

    public List getMembers(){
        return this.members;
    }
    public void setMembers(List members){
        this.members = members;
    }
    public String getRole(){
        return this.role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role){
        this.role = role;
    }
}




import java.util.List;

public class Episodes{
    private String date_dead;
    private String description;
    private String episode_id;
    private String episode_name;
    private String episode_number;
    private String franchise_description;
    private String franchise_id;
    private String franchise_name;
    private String franchise_slug;
    private String guid;
    private String id_from_partner;
    private boolean is_locked;
    private String is_mobile;
    private boolean is_parental_locked;
    private boolean is_subscription;
    private String media_base_url;
    private String metadata_url;
    private String mobile_streams;
    private String network;
    private String network_analytics;
    private String network_id;
    private boolean network_is_dand_enabled;
    private String network_logo;
    private String network_name;
    private String network_slug;
    private String original_air_date;
    private String platforms;
    private String player_type;
    private String playlist_url;
    private String poster_url;
    private String rating;
    private String run_time;
    private String season_number;
    private String season_sort_key;
    private String slug;
    private String ssid;
    private String thumbnail_url;
    private String tms_id;
    private String url;
    private String video_guid;
    private String video_id;
    private String wide_poster_url;

    public String getDate_dead(){
        return this.date_dead;
    }
    public void setDate_dead(String date_dead){
        this.date_dead = date_dead;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getEpisode_id(){
        return this.episode_id;
    }
    public void setEpisode_id(String episode_id){
        this.episode_id = episode_id;
    }
    public String getEpisode_name(){
        return this.episode_name;
    }
    public void setEpisode_name(String episode_name){
        this.episode_name = episode_name;
    }
    public String getEpisode_number(){
        return this.episode_number;
    }
    public void setEpisode_number(String episode_number){
        this.episode_number = episode_number;
    }
    public String getFranchise_description(){
        return this.franchise_description;
    }
    public void setFranchise_description(String franchise_description){
        this.franchise_description = franchise_description;
    }
    public String getFranchise_id(){
        return this.franchise_id;
    }
    public void setFranchise_id(String franchise_id){
        this.franchise_id = franchise_id;
    }
    public String getFranchise_name(){
        return this.franchise_name;
    }
    public void setFranchise_name(String franchise_name){
        this.franchise_name = franchise_name;
    }
    public String getFranchise_slug(){
        return this.franchise_slug;
    }
    public void setFranchise_slug(String franchise_slug){
        this.franchise_slug = franchise_slug;
    }
    public String getGuid(){
        return this.guid;
    }
    public void setGuid(String guid){
        this.guid = guid;
    }
    public String getId_from_partner(){
        return this.id_from_partner;
    }
    public void setId_from_partner(String id_from_partner){
        this.id_from_partner = id_from_partner;
    }
    public boolean getIs_locked(){
        return this.is_locked;
    }
    public void setIs_locked(boolean is_locked){
        this.is_locked = is_locked;
    }
    public String getIs_mobile(){
        return this.is_mobile;
    }
    public void setIs_mobile(String is_mobile){
        this.is_mobile = is_mobile;
    }
    public boolean getIs_parental_locked(){
        return this.is_parental_locked;
    }
    public void setIs_parental_locked(boolean is_parental_locked){
        this.is_parental_locked = is_parental_locked;
    }
    public boolean getIs_subscription(){
        return this.is_subscription;
    }
    public void setIs_subscription(boolean is_subscription){
        this.is_subscription = is_subscription;
    }
    public String getMedia_base_url(){
        return this.media_base_url;
    }
    public void setMedia_base_url(String media_base_url){
        this.media_base_url = media_base_url;
    }
    public String getMetadata_url(){
        return this.metadata_url;
    }
    public void setMetadata_url(String metadata_url){
        this.metadata_url = metadata_url;
    }
    public String getMobile_streams(){
        return this.mobile_streams;
    }
    public void setMobile_streams(String mobile_streams){
        this.mobile_streams = mobile_streams;
    }
    public String getNetwork(){
        return this.network;
    }
    public void setNetwork(String network){
        this.network = network;
    }
    public String getNetwork_analytics(){
        return this.network_analytics;
    }
    public void setNetwork_analytics(String network_analytics){
        this.network_analytics = network_analytics;
    }
    public String getNetwork_id(){
        return this.network_id;
    }
    public void setNetwork_id(String network_id){
        this.network_id = network_id;
    }
    public boolean getNetwork_is_dand_enabled(){
        return this.network_is_dand_enabled;
    }
    public void setNetwork_is_dand_enabled(boolean network_is_dand_enabled){
        this.network_is_dand_enabled = network_is_dand_enabled;
    }
    public String getNetwork_logo(){
        return this.network_logo;
    }
    public void setNetwork_logo(String network_logo){
        this.network_logo = network_logo;
    }
    public String getNetwork_name(){
        return this.network_name;
    }
    public void setNetwork_name(String network_name){
        this.network_name = network_name;
    }
    public String getNetwork_slug(){
        return this.network_slug;
    }
    public void setNetwork_slug(String network_slug){
        this.network_slug = network_slug;
    }
    public String getOriginal_air_date(){
        return this.original_air_date;
    }
    public void setOriginal_air_date(String original_air_date){
        this.original_air_date = original_air_date;
    }
    public String getPlatforms(){
        return this.platforms;
    }
    public void setPlatforms(String platforms){
        this.platforms = platforms;
    }
    public String getPlayer_type(){
        return this.player_type;
    }
    public void setPlayer_type(String player_type){
        this.player_type = player_type;
    }
    public String getPlaylist_url(){
        return this.playlist_url;
    }
    public void setPlaylist_url(String playlist_url){
        this.playlist_url = playlist_url;
    }
    public String getPoster_url(){
        return this.poster_url;
    }
    public void setPoster_url(String poster_url){
        this.poster_url = poster_url;
    }
    public String getRating(){
        return this.rating;
    }
    public void setRating(String rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String getRun_time(){
        return this.run_time;
    }
    public void setRun_time(String run_time){
        this.run_time = run_time;
    }
    public String getSeason_number(){
        return this.season_number;
    }
    public void setSeason_number(String season_number){
        this.season_number = season_number;
    }
    public String getSeason_sort_key(){
        return this.season_sort_key;
    }
    public void setSeason_sort_key(String season_sort_key){
        this.season_sort_key = season_sort_key;
    }
    public String getSlug(){
        return this.slug;
    }
    public void setSlug(String slug){
        this.slug = slug;
    }
    public String getSsid(){
        return this.ssid;
    }
    public void setSsid(String ssid){
        this.ssid = ssid;
    }
    public String getThumbnail_url(){
        return this.thumbnail_url;
    }
    public void setThumbnail_url(String thumbnail_url){
        this.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url;
    }
    public String getTms_id(){
        return this.tms_id;
    }
    public void setTms_id(String tms_id){
        this.tms_id = tms_id;
    }
    public String getUrl(){
        return this.url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getVideo_guid(){
        return this.video_guid;
    }
    public void setVideo_guid(String video_guid){
        this.video_guid = video_guid;
    }
    public String getVideo_id(){
        return this.video_id;
    }
    public void setVideo_id(String video_id){
        this.video_id = video_id;
    }
    public String getWide_poster_url(){
        return this.wide_poster_url;
    }
    public void setWide_poster_url(String wide_poster_url){
        this.wide_poster_url = wide_poster_url;
    }
}





import java.util.List;

public class Genres{
    private String name;
    private String slug;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSlug(){
        return this.slug;
    }
    public void setSlug(String slug){
        this.slug = slug;
    }
}




import java.util.List;

public class Images{
    private String poster_url;
    private String thumbnail_url;
    private String wide_poster_url;

    public String getPoster_url(){
        return this.poster_url;
    }
    public void setPoster_url(String poster_url){
        this.poster_url = poster_url;
    }
    public String getThumbnail_url(){
        return this.thumbnail_url;
    }
    public void setThumbnail_url(String thumbnail_url){
        this.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url;
    }
    public String getWide_poster_url(){
        return this.wide_poster_url;
    }
    public void setWide_poster_url(String wide_poster_url){
        this.wide_poster_url = wide_poster_url;
    }
}




import java.util.List;

public class Networks{
    private String banner;
    private String description;
    private boolean is_locked;
    private String logo;
    private String name;
    private String network_analytics;
    private Number network_id;
    private String slug;
    private String thumbnail_url;
    private String url;

    public String getBanner(){
        return this.banner;
    }
    public void setBanner(String banner){
        this.banner = banner;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    public boolean getIs_locked(){
        return this.is_locked;
    }
    public void setIs_locked(boolean is_locked){
        this.is_locked = is_locked;
    }
    public String getLogo(){
        return this.logo;
    }
    public void setLogo(String logo){
        this.logo = logo;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getNetwork_analytics(){
        return this.network_analytics;
    }
    public void setNetwork_analytics(String network_analytics){
        this.network_analytics = network_analytics;
    }
    public Number getNetwork_id(){
        return this.network_id;
    }
    public void setNetwork_id(Number network_id){
        this.network_id = network_id;
    }
    public String getSlug(){
        return this.slug;
    }
    public void setSlug(String slug){
        this.slug = slug;
    }
    public String getThumbnail_url(){
        return this.thumbnail_url;
    }
    public void setThumbnail_url(String thumbnail_url){
        this.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url;
    }
    public String getUrl(){
        return this.url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
}



import java.util.List;

public class Ratings{
    private String description;
    private String rating;
    private String rating_body;

    public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getRating(){
        return this.rating;
    }
    public void setRating(String rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public String getRating_body(){
        return this.rating_body;
    }
    public void setRating_body(String rating_body){
        this.rating_body = rating_body;
    }
}



import java.util.List;

public class Season_filters{
    private Number episode_count;
    private String name;
    private String slug;

    public Number getEpisode_count(){
        return this.episode_count;
    }
    public void setEpisode_count(Number episode_count){
        this.episode_count = episode_count;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSlug(){
        return this.slug;
    }
    public void setSlug(String slug){
        this.slug = slug;
    }
}


import java.util.List;

public class Slider{
    private Number not_for_kids;
    private Number off_age;
    private Number on_age;
    private String status;
    private Number target_age;
    private String text;

    public Number getNot_for_kids(){
        return this.not_for_kids;
    }
    public void setNot_for_kids(Number not_for_kids){
        this.not_for_kids = not_for_kids;
    }
    public Number getOff_age(){
        return this.off_age;
    }
    public void setOff_age(Number off_age){
        this.off_age = off_age;
    }
    public Number getOn_age(){
        return this.on_age;
    }
    public void setOn_age(Number on_age){
        this.on_age = on_age;
    }
    public String getStatus(){
        return this.status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status){
        this.status = status;
    }
    public Number getTarget_age(){
        return this.target_age;
    }
    public void setTarget_age(Number target_age){
        this.target_age = target_age;
    }
    public String getText(){
        return this.text;
    }
    public void setText(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }
}

import java.util.List;

public class Streams{
    private String date_dead;
    private String franchise_name;
    private String id_from_partner;
    private boolean is_locked;
    private boolean is_parental_locked;
    private boolean is_subscription;
    private String media_base_url;
    private Number mediaview_partner_id;
    private Number mediaview_provider_id;
    private String metadata_url;
    private String network;
    private String network_analytics;
    private String network_id;
    private boolean network_is_dand_enabled;
    private String network_name;
    private String network_slug;
    private String player_type;
    private String playlist_url;
    private String rating;
    private Number run_time;
    private Number selection_score;
    private String ssid;
    private String thumbnail_url;
    private String uma_supported;
    private String url;
    private String video_guid;
    private String video_id;

    public String getDate_dead(){
        return this.date_dead;
    }
    public void setDate_dead(String date_dead){
        this.date_dead = date_dead;
    }
    public String getFranchise_name(){
        return this.franchise_name;
    }
    public void setFranchise_name(String franchise_name){
        this.franchise_name = franchise_name;
    }
    public String getId_from_partner(){
        return this.id_from_partner;
    }
    public void setId_from_partner(String id_from_partner){
        this.id_from_partner = id_from_partner;
    }
    public boolean getIs_locked(){
        return this.is_locked;
    }
    public void setIs_locked(boolean is_locked){
        this.is_locked = is_locked;
    }
    public boolean getIs_parental_locked(){
        return this.is_parental_locked;
    }
    public void setIs_parental_locked(boolean is_parental_locked){
        this.is_parental_locked = is_parental_locked;
    }
    public boolean getIs_subscription(){
        return this.is_subscription;
    }
    public void setIs_subscription(boolean is_subscription){
        this.is_subscription = is_subscription;
    }
    public String getMedia_base_url(){
        return this.media_base_url;
    }
    public void setMedia_base_url(String media_base_url){
        this.media_base_url = media_base_url;
    }
    public Number getMediaview_partner_id(){
        return this.mediaview_partner_id;
    }
    public void setMediaview_partner_id(Number mediaview_partner_id){
        this.mediaview_partner_id = mediaview_partner_id;
    }
    public Number getMediaview_provider_id(){
        return this.mediaview_provider_id;
    }
    public void setMediaview_provider_id(Number mediaview_provider_id){
        this.mediaview_provider_id = mediaview_provider_id;
    }
    public String getMetadata_url(){
        return this.metadata_url;
    }
    public void setMetadata_url(String metadata_url){
        this.metadata_url = metadata_url;
    }
    public String getNetwork(){
        return this.network;
    }
    public void setNetwork(String network){
        this.network = network;
    }
    public String getNetwork_analytics(){
        return this.network_analytics;
    }
    public void setNetwork_analytics(String network_analytics){
        this.network_analytics = network_analytics;
    }
    public String getNetwork_id(){
        return this.network_id;
    }
    public void setNetwork_id(String network_id){
        this.network_id = network_id;
    }
    public boolean getNetwork_is_dand_enabled(){
        return this.network_is_dand_enabled;
    }
    public void setNetwork_is_dand_enabled(boolean network_is_dand_enabled){
        this.network_is_dand_enabled = network_is_dand_enabled;
    }
    public String getNetwork_name(){
        return this.network_name;
    }
    public void setNetwork_name(String network_name){
        this.network_name = network_name;
    }
    public String getNetwork_slug(){
        return this.network_slug;
    }
    public void setNetwork_slug(String network_slug){
        this.network_slug = network_slug;
    }
    public String getPlayer_type(){
        return this.player_type;
    }
    public void setPlayer_type(String player_type){
        this.player_type = player_type;
    }
    public String getPlaylist_url(){
        return this.playlist_url;
    }
    public void setPlaylist_url(String playlist_url){
        this.playlist_url = playlist_url;
    }
    public String getRating(){
        return this.rating;
    }
    public void setRating(String rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }
    public Number getRun_time(){
        return this.run_time;
    }
    public void setRun_time(Number run_time){
        this.run_time = run_time;
    }
    public Number getSelection_score(){
        return this.selection_score;
    }
    public void setSelection_score(Number selection_score){
        this.selection_score = selection_score;
    }
    public String getSsid(){
        return this.ssid;
    }
    public void setSsid(String ssid){
        this.ssid = ssid;
    }
    public String getThumbnail_url(){
        return this.thumbnail_url;
    }
    public void setThumbnail_url(String thumbnail_url){
        this.thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url;
    }
    public String getUma_supported(){
        return this.uma_supported;
    }
    public void setUma_supported(String uma_supported){
        this.uma_supported = uma_supported;
    }
    public String getUrl(){
        return this.url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getVideo_guid(){
        return this.video_guid;
    }
    public void setVideo_guid(String video_guid){
        this.video_guid = video_guid;
    }
    public String getVideo_id(){
        return this.video_id;
    }
    public void setVideo_id(String video_id){
        this.video_id = video_id;
    }
}


and following is the driver I am using to get the name of the shows-

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class BossMan {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        URL jsonUrl = new URL("http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/shows/carousels/featured.json");
        ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonGen jsongen = null;
        jsongen = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, JsonGen.class);
        System.out.println(jsongen.getName());

    }

}
```

but I am facing following error -

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of JsonGen out of START_ARRAY token
     at [Source: http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/shows/carousels/featured.json; line: 1, column: 1]


I need the result in a array but code is failing above exception.
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Any way to narrow this down a bit? See this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show us JsonGen class. If the json file you want to deserialize is an array of objects of type JsonGen then you need to do this:

```
List<JsonGen> jsongen = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<JsonGen>>() {});

for(JsonGen element : jsongen) {
        System.out.println(element.getName())
}
```

Comment: ran out of space , let me know if any specific snippet you are looking for in JsonGen. I am new bee in json

Comment: I have added the declaration snippet of JsonGen.java above.

Comment: Looks good - it reflects what is in json file in given url. Above code snippet with TypeReference<List<JsonGen>>() {} - type reference should work as expected.

Comment: but I am not able to extract the values from object, jsongen refrence is not giving object options to print the json values for name.

Comment: `List<JsonGen> jsongen = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<JsonGen>>() {});`
  `System.out.println(jsongen.);`

Comment: Now jsongen is a list of elements of JsonGen type so you need to iterate over this list to get JsonGen instances. I updated the code snippet.

Comment: I am trying to extract values from name

Comment: Sorry didn't saw your'e updated snippet , let me try and get back to you right now , thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

If the data you receive from the server is an array, you need to pass List.class as the second argument to readValue():

```
List<JsonGen> values = objmapper.readValue(jsonUril, List.class);
```

Comment: I have added the above solution - below is the new driver class -'code' public class BossMan{
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
  
  URL jsonUrl = new URL("http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/shows/carousels/featured.json");
  
  ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonGen jsongen = null;
  //jsongen = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, JsonGen.class);
  List<JsonGen> values = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, List.class);
  
  for (JsonGen temp : values) {
   System.out.println(temp);
  } 'code' but exception again

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to JsonGen
 at BossMan.main(BossMan.java:25)